# to create highest & lowest quartiles of a variable in Stata

Tags: stata

This is the Stata code I used to divide a Winsorised & centred variable (`num_exp`, denoting number of experienced managers) based on 4 quartiles & thereafter to generate the highest & lowest quartile dummies thereof:

```
 egen quartile_num_exp = xtile(WC_num_exp), n(4)
    gen high_quartile_numexp = 1 if quartile_num_exp==4
    (1433 missing values generated);
    gen low_quartile_num_exp = 1 if quartile_num_intlexp==1
    (1062 missing values generated);
```

Thanks everybody - here's the link

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64545449/No%20of%20expeienced%20managers.dta

I did try both Aspen Chen's & Roberto's suggestions - Chen's way of creating high quartile dummy gives the same results as I had earlier & Roberto's - both quartiles show 1 for the same rows - how's that possible?

I forgot to mention here that there are indeed many ties - the range of the original variable `W_num_exp` is from 0 to 7, the mean being 2.126618, i subtracted that from each observation of W_num_exp to get the WC_num_exp.

```
tab high_quartile_numexp shows the same problem I originally had
  le_numexp |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          0 |      1,433       80.64       80.64
          1 |        344       19.36      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |      1,777      100.00
```

Also, I checked `egenmore` is already installed in my Stata version 13.1

What I fail to understand is why the dummy variable based on the highest quartile doesn't have 75% of observations below it (I've got 1777 total observations): to my understanding this dummy variable should be the cut-off point above which exactly 25% of the total no. of observations should lie (as we can see it contains only 19.3% of observations).

Am I doing anything wrong in writing the correct Stata code for high_quartile  low_quartile dummy variables?

Comment: There is no data or output to verfy. Did you check the distribution of `quartile_num_exp`? If the variable (`WC_num_exp` in this case) is highly concentrated at one value, Stata may only be able to find a value that approximates the 75th percentile.

Comment: In any event, `tab high_quartile_numexp` would demonstrate that the code does not generate dummy variables correctly. Consider using `gen high_quartile_numexp=quartile_num_exp==4` instead.

Comment: Some confusion here between quartiles (3 in number) and the bins or classes they delimit (4). Not reproducible without your data. You should document that the `egen` function `xtile()` is to be downloaded using `ssc install egenmore`. Despite this poor formulation, @Aspen Chen's guess at ties is surely on target. The number of experienced managers in principle has values 0, 1, ... and ties are highly likely.

Comment: The comments and answers on your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403529/assigning-rank-to-a-variable-based-on-2-other-variables-in-stata made utterly explicit the importance of showing data with a question like this.

Comment: You missed the point about `egenmore`. You should explain that you are using a user-written program. It's in your interests and everyone's else that your question be clear to others.

Comment: The problem is an analogue of this one: I have values 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,3 and want to see 4 quartile-based bins with equal numbers of values in each. Even with sample size of multiple of 4, that can't be done because of ties.

Comment: Otherwise put, I can see no programming question here. It's purely a statistical question of understanding what is, and what is not, possible when subdividing a variable's range into bins.

Comment: An orthogonal detail: your dummies have values 1 and missing. For just about every purpose, values 1 and 0 are more useful.

Comment: Okay thanks, so stata can't divide a centred variable into quartiles, should try it manually then.

Comment: Sorry, but again you appear to miss the point. No software or manual procedure can do this for your kind of data if you mean produce exactly equal frequencies in each bin wherever ties prohibit that. (Centring is irrelevant here, as it just changes units, and does nothing to ties.) What manual procedure would you use for 4 bins from 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,3?

Comment: Sorry, by manual procedure i meant using approximations which i can do done manually - i guess stata is also doing some sort of that when it's creating the high_quartile variable, but i'm not sure whether i can rely on it for further analyses. thanks so much.

Comment: You've lost me. What the Stata code is doing is not opaque: you can look at the code to see. I don't think you have shown in any sense that an approximation is avoidable here.

Comment: Thanks - yes, you're absolutely right - i did try out the code again on a small part of my sample & also did a manual approximation there of - mine isn't any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset provided answers the question. Consider the tabulation:

```
. tab W_num_exp

num_execs_i |
   ntl_exp, |
 Winsorized |
   fraction |
        .01 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          0 |        297       16.71       16.71
          1 |        418       23.52       40.24
          2 |        436       24.54       64.77
          3 |        282       15.87       80.64
          4 |        171        9.62       90.26
          5 |        109        6.13       96.40
          6 |         34        1.91       98.31
          7 |         30        1.69      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |      1,777      100.00
```

Exactly equal numbers in each of 4 quartile-based bins can be provided if, and only if, there are values with cumulative percents 25, 50, 75. No such values exist. You have to make do with approximations. The approximations can be lousy, but the only alternative, of arbitrarily assigning observations with the same value to different bins to even up frequencies, is statistically indefensible.

(The number of observations needing to be a multiple of 4 for 4 bins, etc., for exactly equal frequencies is also a complication, which bites hard for small datasets, but that is not the major issue here.)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code:

```
clear
set more off

sysuse auto
keep make mpg

*-----

// your way (kind of)
egen mpg4 = xtile(mpg), nq(4)

gen lowq = mpg4 == 1
gen highq = mpg4 == 4

*-----

// what you want
summarize mpg, detail
gen lowq2 = mpg < r(p25)
gen highq2 = mpg < r(p75)

*-----

summarize high* low*
list
```

Now check the listing to see what's going on.

See `help stored results`.